# Android :Why the Activity is in onPause?

Tags: android, android-activity, onpause

I must to know if my Activity is displayed or not. I would to use the method onPause and onResume but I want to know also why the activity is in onPause....
There are 3 cases :

1. Activity in onPause because the display turn off
2. Activity in onPause because the user have clicked the home button
3. Activity in onPause because the user have clicked the home button and screen off

How can I do ? Thanks

EDIT : I resolved with this code :

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getContext().                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

Comment: you should read more carefully the [android activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: I thinks int these three cases activity is not displayed. When a activity is brought to background or destroyed, the `onPause` method is always called.

Answer (score 4):

****1.**** Activity in onPause because the display turn off and if any call appear   :`onPause()` called

****2.****Activity in onPause because the user have clicked the home button :`onUserLeaveHint()` called before `onPause()` if user press home button

****3.****When user press Back key :`onUserInteraction()` called before onPause()

Comment: I was looking for a way to modify exit behavior of my app depending on whether I onPause'd due to a phone call or some other interaction.  onUserLeaveHint() and onUserInteraction() are working much better than the suggestions I've seen on how to monitor that the phone is ringing, which only worked intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

When You leave from one Activity to other Activity the activity from where you are leaving that activity onPause get called. If you want to experiment create all the function Inside the onStart call the other activity onPause of the First activity get called.

For more Information please go through by below link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html